# Rails with Twitter-Bootstrap & simple_form: how to have inline inputs in horizontal form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am using the above and want to have some inline inputs in my horizontal form.
e.g:

```
Zip | City
```

Tried several things, like floating or own divs, but it never worked for me. Further, I would prefer to find a a DSL solution instead of css.

On the other side: would you rather recommend to use twitter_bootstrap_form_for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you consider utilizing Twitter Bootstrap. It's really easy to use and makes routines tasks simple. For example, here is the code that you would use to implement a horizontal inline form:

```
<form class="well form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.